# Update query problem (SQLite for iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, ios4, sqlite

I have a table column containing name of images (e.g Apple.jpg).
All image names have .jpg as extension.

How do I update the extension from .jpg to .png using update statement of SQLite?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET name = substr(name, 1, length(name) - 4) || '.png'
 WHERE name LIKE '%.jpg'
```

Of course, this won't convert the images themselves from JPEG to PNG. (Just to be sure. :-)